# Insert to DataBase Using EntityManager

Tags: java, database, entitymanager

I've been looking for a way to interact with my database using EntityManager class in Java.

The question is related to these two tables I have defined in my DB:

```
PARENT_TABLE:
    PK_ONE
    PK_TWO

CHILD TABLE:
    PK_ONE
    COLUMN
    PK_TWO
```

Here is something I have so far.

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SecondaryTable;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;

@Entity
@Table(name="PARENT_TABLE")
@SecondaryTable(name="CHILD_TABLE", pkJoinColumns={
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="PK_ONE"),
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="PK_TWO")})
public class ExampleTbl implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="PK_ONE")
    private String pkOne;

    @Id
    @Column(name="COLUMN", table="CHILD_TABLE")
    private String column;

    @Column(name="PK_TWO")
    private String pkTwo;

    //GETTERS AND SETTERS
}
```

My questions are:

To be able to Insert to the PARENT_TABLE a new row, do I have to create a new Entity class with just two fields (PK_ONE, PK_TWO) to be able to use the merge() or persist() method?

Will I have to create another Entity class to Insert a new row to my CHILD_TABLE?

To retrieve a List with the existing data I have a method something like this:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<ExampleTbl> getFoldersList() {
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
        Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM ExampleTbl e WHERE e.pkTwo = :pkTwo ORDER BY e.pkOne");
            q.setParameter("pkTwo", "My Test");
        List<ExampleTbl> result = q.getResultList();
        return result;
    }
```

Do you think this is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think its a question with a couple of possible answers. I would recommend reviewing some of the ways they set things up in the Java EE 6 tutorial examples. You can read about that at http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giqst.html